# Wordpress Htaccess - stop subdirectory auto redirecting to root index

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a subdirectory on wordpress

http://wpsite.com/codeigniter,
http://wpsite.com/someothersubdir

But when I go to that url, it always redirects back to the wordpress site with the "page not found"

Here is the wordpress root htaccess file

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How can I make sub directories separate from wordpress?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/codeigniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/someothersubdir/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was in the htaccess of the subfolder (where I have another wordpress running, for testing purposes). So I had to change the `.htaccess` of the subfolder to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /someothersubdir
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```